# Error trying to build a jar with springboot and maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, executable-jar

I'm developing a simple REST service to return HARDCODE data and I'm stuck trying to build the jar of the project. After I check the REST worked well I tried to create the JAR but I couldn't.

Currently this is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>technical_test</groupId>
    <artifactId>technical_test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>technical_test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <Relase>17</Relase>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Currently this is the error when I executed mvn clean package

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) on project technical_test: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported.

Initially the project was with JAVA 21 but I got the same error

Ok, is not supported. How can I found a supported versión (in maven documentation is not clear for my) or how can I fix this error?

I'm new in this, so I'll be please with your help

Comment: This implies ` release version 17 not supported.` you are not using JDK17+ ... also the configuration in maven-compiler-plugin is wrong.. furthermore I assume you have a spring boot project if so you should simply set `<java.version>17</java.version>` if you are not inheriting from the spring-boot-parent.. ?

Comment: All the things like `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` is not required... everything is already done in the parent ... ?

Comment: Also why using old hibernate versions? Spring Boot has already hibernate 6.4+ in there so defining an older version does not make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>technical_test</groupId>
    <artifactId>technical_test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>technical_test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

I have used `java.version` in that setup but that's no even required because it's defined in the parent.

I also strongly recommend to remove hibernate-jpa-2.1-api in that version because Spring Boot already offers an appropriate version... which is at version: 6.4.1.Final... Check also the documentation... also the groupId has changed for Hibernate...

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
     ...
  </dependency>
```

This is also valid for servlet-api ... that has been changed in the namespace... (groupId) based on Jakarta EE Change

*Update*

The output for `mvn --version` should like this:

```
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /Users/../tools/maven
Java version: 17.0.10, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Users/.../.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem
Default locale: en_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.0", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that Maven is unable to compile your code with Java version 17, as it seems that the Maven compiler plugin you're using doesn't support it. so either Update Maven Compiler Plugin or use a lower java version,
also Relase should be release in the configuration of the maven-compiler-plugin.

```
       <configuration>
            <release>17</release>
            <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: That simply not correct. The problem is related to the used JDK version which is not JDK17+...with Maven you are able to compile everything up to JDK23... (which is currently avaiable in EA builds)...(https://github.com/khmarbaise/jdk23)

Comment: @khmarbaise How can I check that and fix that it is needed?

Comment: @JuanDavidPolo as I wrote... check the JDK which is used ... `mvn --version` and post the output here...or update your question..

Comment: @khmarbaise this is the result
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\Users\juand\Downloads\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Users\juand\AppData\Local\jdk-11.0.2
Default locale: es_CO, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: That's what I expected you have not correctly defined your `JAVA_HOME` to point to JDK 17... that's the reason why you can't compile that... Your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to JDK11... that's the reason for the error...